# Memory ordering of non-atomic object access

Tags: c, multithreading, x86, stdatomic, memory-model

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void write(int *j, _Atomic int *i){
    *j = rand();
    atomic_store_explicit(i, 1, memory_order_release);
}

void read(int *j, _Atomic int *i){
    if(atomic_load_explicit(i, memory_order_acquire)){
        int var = *j;
        atomic_store_explicit(i, 0, memory_order_release);
    }
}
```

[**godbolt live example**](https://godbolt.org/z/nohfab6fv)

Assuming that `int *j` and `_Atomic int *i` are unrelated memory locations refering to the same objects in both of the functions and 2 separate threads run each functions in an infinite loop is the following true:

If `atomic_load_explicit(i, memory_order_acquire)` reads a value written by `atomic_store_explicit(i, 1, memory_order_release)` then `int var = *j;` reads a value written by `*j = rand();` exactly in the same iteration?

---

**My understanding**:

1. `*j = rand();` is *Sequenced before* `atomic_store_explicit(i, 1, memory_order_release);` since these are 2 statements in program order.
2. If `atomic_load_explicit(i, memory_order_acquire)` reads a value written by `atomic_store_explicit(i, 1, memory_order_release);` then `atomic_load_explicit(i, memory_order_acquire)` *synchronizes with* `atomic_store_explicit(i, 1, memory_order_release);`
3. Similarly `atomic_load_explicit(i, memory_order_acquire)` is *Sequenced before* `int var = *j;`.
4. Therefore `*j = rand();` *inter-thread happens before* `int var = *j;`.

Accroding to `5.1.2.4/p20` `*j = rand();` is *a visible side effect* with respect to `int var = *j;`

**QUESTION:** Is it really possible to provide visibility guarantees even on ***non-atomic object*** if there are `acquire`-`release` operations in between with *synchronize-with* relations?

The main question is if `*j = rand();` might be reordered with `atomic_store_explicit(i, 1, memory_order_release);` or similarly `atomic_load_explicit(i, memory_order_acquire` might be reordered with `int var = *j;`

---

On `x86` reads and writes are not reordered with like operations so assembly code compiled for `x86` cannot provide a counter-example.

Comment: Your understanding sounds correct. No, those can't be reordered like this, under the as-if rule.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This is actually what I couldn't prove myself. It'd be clear if `acquire`/`release` operation introduce some sort of barrier. Do you have an idea what might prevent such reordering from happening?

Comment: *"what might prevent such reordering"* You mean guarantees in the standard applied to the compilers? Or reordering by CPU at runtime?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Regarding reording by CPU at runtime I guess it can't happen at least for compiled code on x86 since reads and write are not reordered with like operations. But this still does not prevent reordering at compile time.

Comment: What more do you need other than the as-if rule? You said yourself why it's legal. Compilers can't break legal code on a whim.

Comment: Compilers limit their optimizations to things that would be safe even with any hypothetical other thread that might be synchronizing with this thread and establishing a happens-before.  So the C++ rules about creating happens-before relationships can be mapped to sequences of asm (https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html), and appropriate limits on compile-time reordering for CPU memory models in terms of accessing coherent cache.   (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).

Comment: And see also https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/ - *In the new C++11 (formerly known as C++0x) atomic library standard, **every non-relaxed atomic operation acts as a compiler barrier as well***.  (Not necessarily a full barrier; one-way reordering is allowed for most operations.)  This is necessary *because* C++ happens-before guarantees visibility for all objects, including non-atomic, and this is how compilers implement it.

Comment: @PeterCordes _every non-relaxed atomic operation acts as a compiler barrier as well_ I would say it directly implies from the definition. Relaxed operations do not introduced _synchronized-with_ relations. For 2 arbitrary consecutive statements there's the  _Sequenced before_ relation. Combined with _inter-thread happens before_ introduced by **non-relaxed operations** it can be used for proving _happens before_ relation between 2 non-atomic objects.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that looks like the correct terminology in ISO C++'s formalism, which in practice leaves the only sane way to implement acquire and release atomics being with the ordering restrictions shown in https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ for both compile-time and run-time.  (If you only need compile-time ordering, you can use `relaxed` with `atomic_signal_fence(acquire)`, `release`, or `seq_cst`.)

Comment: @SomeName: The compiler *itself* is what has to prevent compile-time reordering: by simply, well, not doing it.  If it sees an `atomic_store` with `memory_order_release`, then it needs to make note of this, and not reorder it with any earlier loads or stores (be they atomic or not).  A compiler that does reorder in this case is buggy / non-conforming.

Comment: "2 separate threads run each functions **in an infinite loop**": You don't really mean that, do you?  If `write` is executed in a loop, then its second and further iterations are not synchronized with the reader thread in any way, and they cause a data race with the reads.  If you really do want them in a loop, then you need the write to be guarded by something like `if (!atomic_load_explicit(i, memory_order_acquire))`, and you've now created a primitive kind of mutex.